# GWT Compiler error missing core libraries of java

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, libgdx

I am trying to compile my libgdx project with the gwt plugin inside of eclipse. The compiler gives the following message:

```
Apr 11, 2019 10:42:09 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Public resources found in...
   Unexpected entry in classpath; C:\my-gdx-game-core\bin\default is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
Translatable source found in...
Public resources found in...
   Unexpected entry in classpath; C:\my-gdx-game-core\bin\default is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
Translatable source found in...
Persistent unit cache dir set to: C:\Users\thebi\Documents\Backed Up\src\java\another-tst\html\gwt-unitCache
Looking for previously cached Compilation Units in C:\Users\thebi\Documents\Backed Up\src\java\another-tst\html\gwt-unitCache
Compiling module com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinitionSuperdev
   Looking for precompiled archives.  To disable, use -Dgwt.usearchives=false
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
gwt-unitCache-c04dfa348afbdd12c2a9ddc3bc36901a78fa6812-0000016A0CCE0AE0: Load complete
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/UI.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/DOM.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/thebi/.p2/pool/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201710131939/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/RemoteService.gwtar
   Found 3831 cached/archived units.  Used 3831 / 3831 units from cache.
   Compiling...
      Compilation completed in 0.00 seconds
   Added 46 units to cache since last cleanup.
Wrote 46 units to persistent cache.
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream'
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.java'
         Line 28: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtNet'
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtNet.java'
         Line 73: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/net/Socket.java'
         Line 41: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/Net.java'
         Line 80: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandleStream'
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandleStream.java'
         Line 55: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/GwtFileHandle.java'
         Line 103: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.java'
         Line 78: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java'
         Line 19: No source code is available for type java.io.FilterInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         Line 20: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/java/io/Reader.java'
         Line 33: No source code is available for type java.io.Closeable; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/preloader/Preloader.java'
         Line 203: No source code is available for type java.io.ByteArrayInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

There is a lot more than this, but it is much of the same. Mostly just java.io issues.

Comment: Try going into the java build path for your project, go to order and export, make sure gwt is at the top of the list.

Comment: package 'java.io.* is not part of the JRE emulation library and therefore can not be translated. You can not use InputStream on the client side. If this classes are used on the server side, check your module descriptor.

Comment: @ElHoss java.io is part of the JRE emulation library.  http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Comment: oh, yes, you are right. I missed that one.

Comment: I moved the gwt to the top of the list, but the error still happened.

Comment: While there is some `java.io` emulation, `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream` is not on that list. I think that `InputStream` is a newer addition (May 2015), but it looks like you are using GWT 2.7, a fairly old build (Nov 2014)?

Comment: I used the newer version, and it appeared to work for a very simple libgdx project. Once I can extend it to the project which I was working on previously I will let you know if the problem did not appear again!

Comment: After adding the new content, I get the following error: ```Hint: Your source appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client'; no problem, but you'll need to use the <source> directive in your module to make it accessible. ``` I did not change any of the packages or names. I did not add or remove any packages.